# Best way to find_or_create_by_id but update the attributes if the record is found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking for a clean way to create a record with a set of attributes if the record does not exist and - if the record do exist - to update its attributes. I love the syntax of the block in the find_or_create_by_id call. Here's my code:

```
@categories = Highrise::DealCategory.find(:all)

@categories.each do |category|
  puts "Category: #{category.name}"

  Category.find_or_create_by_id(category.id) do |c|
    c.name = category.name
  end
end
```

The problem here is that if the record exists but the name has changed, it is not being updated.

Looking for a clean solution to this problem...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578625/find-or-create-by-in-rails-3-and-updating-for-creating-records/5580108#5580108

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own method:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_id_or_create(id, &block)
    obj = self.find_by_id( id ) || self.new
    yield obj
    obj.save
  end
end
```

usage

```
 Category.find_by_id_or_create(10) do |c|
   c.name = "My new name"
 end
```

Of course, in this way you should extend `method missing` method and implement this method in the same way as others `find_by_something` methods. But for being short this will be enough.

Comment: beautiful. Just what i needed!

Comment: you may be able to simplify this with [upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert)

Answer (score 1):

I have coded this finders that can be used for different scenarios.

**The most important thing is, that it removes the parameter `:id` on create and update.**

Creating a model with `:id` can cause problems with `MySql` or `PostgreSQL` because Rails uses the auto sequence number of the database. If you create new model instances with an `:id` you can get a `UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

```
# config/initializers/model_finders.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.find_by_or_create(attributes, &block)
    self.find_by(attributes) || self.create(attributes.except(:id), &block)
  end


  def self.find_by_or_create!(attributes, &block)
    self.find_by(attributes) || self.create!(attributes.except(:id), &block)
  end


  def self.find_or_create_update_by(attributes, &block)
    self.find_by(attributes).try(:update, attributes.except(:id), &block) || self.create(attributes.except(:id), &block)
  end


  def self.find_or_create_update_by!(attributes, &block)
    self.find_by(attributes).try(:update!, attributes.except(:id), &block) || self.create!(attributes.except(:id), &block)
  end


  def self.find_by_or_initialize(attributes, &block)
    self.find_by(attributes) || new(attributes.except(:id), &block)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is using Ruby's [tap](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method, like this:

```
Category.find_or_initialize_by(id: category.id).tap do |c|
  c.name = category.name
  c.save
end
```

Also, I changed `find_or_create_by_id` to `find_or_initialize_by`, otherwise it will hit the database twice.

`find_or_initialize_by` finds or intitializes a record, then returns it. We then tap into it, make our updates and save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I did this yesterday, wishing there was a way to do it in a one-liner.

Ended up going with (using your code):

```
c = Category.find_or_initialize_by_id(category.id)
c.name = category.name
c.save
```

Perhaps there is a nicer way, but this is what I used.

[Edit: use initialize instead of create to avoid hitting the DB twice)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yea, that's what i was hoping to improve. FYI i'm pretty sure you should use find_or_initialize_by_id to not hit the db twice.

Comment: you can use tap if you really want to make it a one-liner

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c = Category.find_or_initialize_by_id(category.id)
c.name = category.name
c.save!
```

This way you only save the instance once, instead of twice, if you called `find_or_create_by_id` (assuming it's a new record).

Answer (score 0):

I liked fl00r's answer. But why do we have to save the object every time?
We can check if its already there in records or else save it

```
def self.find_or_create_by_id(id, &block)
    obj = self.find_by_id(id) 
    unless obj
      obj = self.create(id: id)
    end
    obj
end
```

Comment: `self.create(id: id)` is not a good idea. This can cause a duplicate key unique constraint error `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint`. Please use `self.new` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this patten for seeds:

```
Category.find_or_initialize_by(id: category.id).update |c|
  c.name = category.name
end
```

It works the same as Dale Wijnand's and Teoulas answers (only saves the instance once) but uses a block like in your question.

Comment: I don't know if this used to work, but in recent versions of Rails the update method doesn't take a block as an argument, so this won't work