# find_or_create_by in Rails 3 and updating for creating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, dynamic-finders

I'm not sure if I should be updating records this way or if I'm missing something.

I have a table with 5 columns (not including timestamps and id) 3 of which are distinct, and 2 which will get updated.  The 3 distinct which I will find or create by are room_id, date, and source.  The other 2 are price and spots available (these change hourly, daily etc.)

My question is, should I first find or create the record, then update (or create) the price and spots or can I do it all at once?  You can see the two ways I'm doing it now, and I'm not sure if its actually doing what I'm expecting.

Also, is there any downside to do a find_and_create_by like this?

Thanks

```
  private

  def self.parse_data(params,data)
    data.beds.each do |bed|
      room = Room.find_or_create_room(bed.title, params[:id])

      #find clones somehow
      #puts bed.nights.first.price
      bed.nights.each_with_index do |night,index|
        available = Available.find_or_create_by_room_id_and_bookdate_and_source(
          :room_id => room.id, 
          :bookdate => (params[:date].to_date)+index, 
          :source => data.class.to_s#,
          #:price => night.price
        )
        #available.price = night.price
        #available.spots = night.spots
        #available.save
      end

    end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160073/best-way-to-find-or-create-by-id-but-update-the-attributes-if-the-record-is-found/5160233#5160233

Comment: you may be able to simplify this with [upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is two approaches.

[**First**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160073/best-way-to-find-or-create-by-id-but-update-the-attributes-if-the-record-is-found/5160233#5160233) you can extend `Available` with exact method you need:

```
def self.find_or_create_by_room_id_and_bookdate_and_source(room_id, bookdate, source, &block)
  obj = self.find_by_room_id_and_bookdate_and_source( room_id, bookdate, source ) || self.new(:room_id => room_id, :bookdate => bookdate, :source => source)
  yield obj
  obj.save
end
```

usage

```
Available.find_or_create_by_room_id_and_bookdate_and_source(room.id, (params[:date].to_date)+index, data.class.to_s) do |c|
  c.price = night.price
  c.spots = night.spots
end
```

This is awkward. So for being more flexible you can create `update_or_create_by...` method for `ActiveRecord` using `method_missing` magic:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.method_missing(method_id, *args, &block)
    method_name = method_id.to_s
    if method_name =~ /^update_or_create_by_(.+)$/
      update_or_create($1, *args, &block)
    else
      super
    end
  end
  def self.update_or_create(search, *args, &block)
    parameters = search.split("_and_")
    params = Hash[ parameters.zip(args) ]
    obj = where(params).first || self.new(params)
    yield obj
    obj.save
    obj
  end
end
```

So now you can use it:

```
Available.update_or_create_by_id_and_source(20, "my_source") do |a|
  a.whatever = "coooool"
end
```

Comment: This is an awesome idea; but I get this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by_id' for #<Class:0x9aaad6c>):
  config/initializers/active_record_monkey_patch.rb:7:in `method_missing'

Comment: You shouldn't! :) looks like you haven't got `id` field for your class. Can you write a test?

Comment: Beautiful solution! Though, I get the same error as @DavidRyder when using another dynamic method in the same file (or indirectly using a gem that uses a dynamic method). For instance, find_or_create_by_* gives a undefined method error. So I suspect the `super` part isn't working.

Comment: In @David Ryder's case it raises an error from super method (line 7) so it means that something wrong in AR method_missing.

Comment: @fl00r That's the error I'm getting as well. Don't you get an error when trying to run one of the normal dynamic finders, like Available.find_or_create_by_room_id ? What about on another class, like Room.find_or_create_by_room_id ? (BTW: I'm inserting the ActiveRecord class code in the same file where I make all the calls..).

Comment: It seems dangerous to me to overload ActiveRecord's method_missing in this way, so I went with your first suggestion (extending the class).

Answer (score 24):

Actually, there is a way without any hacking.
Instead of find_or_create_by you can use find_or_initialize_by and set updated atributes with tap

```rb
Available.find_or_initialize_by_room_id_and_bookdate_and_source(
  room.id, 
  (params[:date].to_date)+index, 
  data.class.to_s#
).tap do |a|
  a.price = night.price
  a.spots = night.spots
end.save!
```

Initially this can seems cluttered, but it is doing exactly what you asked for.
Find the record, instanciate it if not found and update atributes.
this could be called "find_and_update_or_create_by", fortunatelly nobody did that. ;)
Hope this help.

Comment: This is not saving the new records!?

Comment: Have you got a tap before the **do** block?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is using Ruby's [tap](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method, like this:

```
def self.parse_data(params,data)
  data.beds.each do |bed|
    room = Room.find_or_create_room(bed.title, params[:id])

    bed.nights.each_with_index do |night,index|
      Available.find_or_initialize_by(room_id: room.id).tap do |available|
        available.bookdate = (params[:date].to_date) + index
        available.source = data.class.to_s
        available.price = night.price
        available.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`find_or_initialize_by` finds or intitializes a record, then returns it. We then tap into it, make our updates and save it to the database.