# rails build or update method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, associations, model-associations

I'm currently using the find or create method to update an associated record which i use to store cached information, but I'm wondering if there's some simpler alternative method similar to build since the object is a `has_one` relation.  The problem with just using build_ is in most cases the object will exist and needs to be updated.  I could use a bunch of ifs the check but wondered if there was some better rails-fu than I'm using currently.

```
  def self.update_caches(data)
    cache = SpaceCache.find_or_create_by_space_id(@space.id)
    cache.rating = ((data.ratings.sum / data.ratings.size)/20).round
    cache.price_min = @space.availables.recent.average(:minimum)
    cache.price_avg = @space.availables.recent.average(:price)
    cache.save
  end
```

Bonus:

I also read here:

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

That the rails calculation methods average, sum, etc will be depreciated in 3.1, so should I'm unsure if I should be replacing them?

```
count(column, options)
average(column, options)
minimum(column, options)
maximum(column, options)
sum(column, options)
calculate(operation, column, options)
```

Comment: you can try this create_or_update method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578625/find-or-create-by-in-rails-3-and-updating-for-creating-records/5580108#5580108

Answer (score 4):

I wrote one for my `has_one :event`.

```
  def build_or_update_event(params)
    result = new_record? ? build_event(params) : event.update_attributes(params)
    result != false
  end
```