# Rails - How to use Find Or Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
@permission = @group.permissions.create(
  :user_id => @user.id,
  :role_id => 2,
  :creator_id => current_user.id)
```

How can I update that to be `find_or_create`, so that if this record already exists, it's assigned to `@permission`, and if it doesn't exist, the record is created?

Comment: i posted a rail4 answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29243322/1536309

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Related topic:

> [find_or_create_by in Rails 3 and updating for creating records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578625/find-or-create-by-in-rails-3-and-updating-for-creating-records/5580108#5580108)

You can extend ActiveRecord with your own `update_or_create` method (see related topic) and then you can use this

```
@permission = Permission.update_or_create_by_user_id_and_role_id_and_creator_id(@user.id, 2, current_user.id) do |p|
  p.group_id = @group.id
end
```

Or you can use `find_or_create_by...` method:

```
@permission = Permission.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_role_id_and_creator_id(@user.id, 2, current_user.id)
@permission.group = @group
@permission.save
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but got: NoMethodError (undefined method `update_or_create_by_user_id_and_role_id_and_creator_id' for #<Class:0x10f62d8a0>):

Comment: Because you should extend it by yourself (look into related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578625/find-or-create-by-in-rails-3-and-updating-for-creating-records/5580108#5580108)

Comment: While I got the find_or_create_by method working, I just noticed that every save is updating an existing group permission. Meaning a user can only belong to one group versus multiple.

Comment: Eeehmm. It isn't connected actually. User can belon as many groups as it wants. Clarify what you mean

Comment: answer with rails3 & rails4 versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29243322/1536309

Answer (score 52):

While the [accepted answer is correct](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) it's important to note that in Rails 4 this syntax will be changing (and the hash syntax). You should be writing the following:

```
@permission = Permission.where(
  user_id: @user.id, 
  role_id: 2, 
  creator_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
```

Which actually looks much closer to your original method! See the sub-section [Deprecated Finders](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) for more details.

Comment: You know what else will be changing? The old hash syntax. You might want to update your answer. Should be, for example: `user_id: @user.id`.

Comment: That would be a change to Ruby not Rails ;) Might want to update your comment to reflect this...and unless you are close friends with developers in charge of completely removing the old hash rocket syntax from Ruby, I would retract your statement completely. The developer's post at the following SO link explains why, and although this was written in 2012, it is still valid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/1629012

Answer (score 7):

I'm updating questions with versioned answers. Because its important.

---

### Rails 4 ([docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.8/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by))

There are a few ways to "find or create" an object, one is `find_or_create_by(args)`

```
Client.find_or_create_by(email: "bambam@flinstones.com", phone: "4255551212")
```

**But the *community preferred* way** is using `where`

`client = Client.where(email: "bambam@flinstones.com", phone: "4255551212").first_or_create`

and then you can do something like:

```
client = Client.where(client_params.slice(:email, :phone)).first_or_create
client.update(client_params)
```

---

### Rails 3 ([docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object))

> Suppose you want to find a client named ‘Andy’, and if there’s none,
>   create one and additionally set his locked attribute to false. You can
>   do so by running:

```
client = Client.where(:first_name => 'Andy').first_or_create(:locked => false)
# => #<Client id: 1, first_name: "Andy", orders_count: 0, locked: false, created_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27", updated_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27">
```

Comment: @ethicalhack3r because `find_or_create_by` it another abstraction away from the SQL that is happening when you call the method.

Answer (score 2):

Or you wanna try this if you have many fields to fill in:

```
conditions = { :user_id => @user.id, 
               :role_id => 2,
               :creator_id => current_user.id }

    @permission = group.permissions.find(:first, :conditions => conditions) || group.permissions.create(conditions)
```

see this post:
[How can I pass multiple attributes to find_or_create_by in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997034/how-can-i-pass-multiple-attributes-to-find-or-create-by-in-rails-3)

Comment: `group.permissions.where(:conditions => conditions).limit(1)` would probably work a little better as it won't be deprecated in Rails 3.1.