# Ruby hash rockets vs 1.9 syntax

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Railscast [Episode 275 - How I test](https://github.com/railscasts/episode-275/blob/master/auth-after/app/models/user.rb) uses the following code to send password resets to users:

```
def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  ....
  ... etc
end

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

My question regards the penultimate line of code: `end while User.exists?(column => self[column])` which works fine as is, but causes my specs to fail if I swap out the hash-rocket i.e. `end while User.exists?(column: self[column])`

```
Failure/Error: user.send_password_reset
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.column: SELECT  1 FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."column" = 'Y7JJV4VAKBbf77zKFVH7RQ' LIMIT 1
```

Why is this happening? Are there situations where you must use a hash-rocket, and are there any guidelines regarding this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`column` in that line of code isn't a symbol, its a variable, so you need to use the hash rocket. `column: self[column]` would build a hash where the key was the symbol `:column`, not the value of the variable `column`, which is what you want.

The new syntax is just a shortcut when using a literal symbol for a key (`key: value` instead of `:key => value`). If you are using a variable key the `=>` syntax is still required.

Comment: Not just any symbols, only symbols that are valid labels. `:$set`, for example, requires the hashrocket as do many other valid symbols. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/479863