# ruby new hash colon notation with string keys

Tags: ruby

Using ruby 1.9.3, string keys don't seem to work with Hash colon notation:

```
1.9.3p194 :005 > {abc: 5}
 => {:abc=>5} 

1.9.3p194 :004 > {'abc': 5}
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
{'abc': 5}
       ^
```

I think I'm running the right version of Ruby

```
1.9.3p194 :006 > RUBY_ENGINE
 => "ruby" 
1.9.3p194 :007 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.9.3"
```

Comment: There is a feature request open for this - http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4801

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That's correct - the new colon notation for hashes only works when the keys are symbols.

Sorry, that's just how it is.

*Update*: general symbols are supported using the new notation in ruby 2.2 and later (strings *as* keys still aren't):

```
irb
2.2.2 :001 > {'abc': 5}
=> {:abc=>5}
```

Comment: Only works when the keys are *some* symbols. For example, you can't use it with `:$set` or `:'pan.cakes'`.

Comment: @muistooshort - Fair point. I suspected as much, but couldn't find evidence in pickaxe. Have you got a citation?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How are people handling this? Just using the rocket hash notation when you have a string?

Comment: I don't have a citation, I read the C source to figure out what's allowed because I couldn't find an authoritative definition. I think it is, more or less, `^[a-zA-Z_]\w*`.

Comment: @phillee: Yes, you have to use the hashrocket except for a certain set of symbols. We've been over this a few times already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8675314/479863, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/479863, and several others that I can't find right now.