# numbers as key in ruby 1.9.x syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

How would I create a hash with numbers as keys under the new ruby syntax?  for example `{abc: 123}` creates a hash with the symbol `abc` as the key, but `{123: 'abc' }` throws an exception (as does `{123.to_sym: 'abc'}`.  The exception I see is `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end`.  I can do  `hash[123] = 'abc'` or  `Hash[123, 200]`, and could do `{123 => 'abc'}` under the old syntax but don't see how to create `{123: 'abc'}` under the new JSON style syntax.

Comment: You don't, AFAIK. The new syntax is syntactic sugar for a specific construct, symbols, and numbers don't turn in to symbols.

Comment: The JavaScript-style notation only works with [some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8675314/479863) [symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/479863), if your key isn't a symbol or is a symbol but not a valid label, then you have to use the hashrocket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between the \`:key => "value"\` and \`key: "value"\` hash notations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The syntax is for keys which are `Symbol`s that are also valid Ruby identifiers. `123` is a `Fixnum`, not a `Symbol`, and even if it *were* a `Symbol`, it still wouldn't be a valid Ruby identifier.

Comment: bummer, but thanks for taking the time to answer Jörg. Seems like there should be a simple way to convert, but I couldn’t figure it out. I'm going to keep this open for a little bit to see if anyone else has a different take. If not I'll give you credit for the answer since I'm also leaning toward it not being possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider 123 is already a symbol because 123 is as unique as a symbol. so {123: "abc"}

is not possible.