# How to create a symbol from a string that has whitespaces?

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

I am creating a Ruby hash for movie names storage.

When the hash's keys are strings that contains whitespaces, it works just fine.

As in:

`movies = {"Avatar" => 5, "Lord of the rings" => 4, "Godfather" => 4}`

Now I am trying to replace the use of strings with symbols:

`movies = {Avatar: 5, Lord of the rings: 4, Godfather: 4}`

Obviously that doesn't work.

How does Ruby handle whitespaces in symbol naming?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try by yourself

```
"Lord of the rings".to_sym
#=> :"Lord of the rings"
```

Comment: but why this is not working ? movies = {Avatar: 3, "Lord of the rings": 4 }  However it does movies = {Avatar: 3, :"Lord of the rings" => 4 }

Comment: @swapnesh: That doesn't work because the JavaScript-style notation only works with [some symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/479863) and [symbols with spaces don't qualify.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8675314/479863)

Comment: Note that this solution will apparently create a string instance, and then resolve or create a matching symbol instance (unless the optimizer is smart enough to avoid that). Declaring a symbol with the `:"<name>"` syntax should simply resolve or create the symbol without creating and discarding a string object first. So -- if the purpose of using symbols is to optimize...

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why you want to use symbols when you want spaces in the key values, but you can do that. You just can't do it using the `<symbol>: <value>` syntax...

```
{:Avatar => 5, :"Lord of the rings" => 4, :Godfather => 4}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this just bcoz symbols are better than strings in term of memory and execution +1 for the answer

Answer (score 3):

To make a symbol with spaces, enter a colon followed by a quoted String. For your example, you would enter:

```
movies = {:Avatar => 5, :'Lord of the rings' => 4, :Godfather => 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but another way to get around this is to do the following:

```
movies = Hash.new

movies["the little mermaid".to_sym] = 4
```