# Colon prefixed string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, and just came across this code snippet:

```
rr = {
  id: 215043,
  :'Official Name' => "Google, Inc."
}
```

What bugs be the most is this `:'Official Name' =>`. It looks like a symbol with spaces.

And when I print it, I see:

```
{:id=>"215043", :"Official Name"=>"Google, Inc."}
```

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Consider: `"cat".to_sym #=> :cat`, `"cat 9 lives".to_sym #=> :"cat 9 lives"`, `"9lives".to_sym #=> :"9lives"`. What can you deduce from these results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What bugs be the most is this `:'Official Name' =>`. It looks like a symbol with white spaces.

That's exactly what it is.

```
p :'Official Name'.class
# => Symbol
```

However, in a Hash literal you can put the colon at the end instead, which I think reads a little nicer:

```
rr = {
  id: 215043,
  "Official Name": "Google, Inc.",
}

rr.keys.each {|key| p [key, key.class] }
# => [:id, Symbol]
#    [:"Official Name", Symbol]
```

For future reference, the [official docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/) are fairly easy to navigate once you get used to them. In this case, you'll want to follow the link for [doc/syntax/literals.rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html), then check out the sections on [Symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols) and [Hashes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes).

Comment: Also wild: `x="Google"; :"#{x}, Inc."` is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is still a [symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html).

Ruby lets you define a symbol that has spaces in it if you wrap it in quotes like that.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15353567/1743874) to see an example of a symbol with spaces being created from a String.