# no implicit conversion of nil into String when using hash without =>

Tags: ruby

my program works fine with this hash

```
hash = 
    {
    'keyone'=> 'valueone',
    'keytwo'=> 'valuetwo',
    'keythree'=> 'valuethree'
    }
```

but someone pointed out the this notation is old and that now I should use:

```
  hash = 
        {
        'keyone': 'valueone',
        'keytwo': 'valuetwo',
        'keythree': 'valuethree'
        }
```

I get this error:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

I only changed the hash notation.
Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: For non symbol keys, you must use `=>`. See [mu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/5025116) answer.

Comment: _"my program works fine with this hash"_ – despite the missing commas?

Comment: @Stefan Sorry, I forgot to write the commas here, but I have them in my code xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latter your keys are saved as symbols. So you should refer to them as:

```
hash[:keyone]
```

And if symbols are just fine, this is even better

```
hash = {
  keyone: 'valueone',
  keytwo: 'valuetwo',
  keythree: 'valuethree'
}
```

But, if you need string keys, you have to stick with the "old" syntax

```
hash = {
  'keyone' => 'valueone',
  'keytwo' => 'valuetwo',
  'keythree' => 'valuethree'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I only changed the hash notation.

No, you didn't. You also changed the type of the key objects from `String`s to `Symbol`s.

```
{ 'key': 'value' }
```

is *not* equivalent to

```
{ 'key' => 'value' }
```

it is equivalent to

```
{ :key => 'value' }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [new notation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes) uses symbols for keys:

```
hash = {
    keyone: 'valueone',
    keytwo: 'valuetwo',
    keythree: 'valuethree'
}
puts hash
# {:keyone=>"valueone", :keytwo=>"valuetwo", :keythree=>"valuethree"}
```

Your code also misses the commas between the items.