# Rails - is this bad practice or can this be optimized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Would this be considered bad practice?

```
unless Link.exists?(:href => 'example.com/somepage')
  Domain.where(:domain => 'example.com').first.links.create(:href => 'example.com/somepage', :text => 'Some Page')
end
```

I realize I might be requesting more data then I actually need, can I optimize this somehow?

Domain is a unique index so the lookup should be fairly quick.

Running Rails 3.0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor your code in this manner:

### Domain class

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
end
```

### Link class

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :domain

  validates :href,
            :uniqueness => true

  attr :domain_url

  def domain_url=(main_domain_url)
    self.domain = Domain.where(domain: main_domain_url).first ||
                  Domain.new(domain: main_domain_url)
  end

  def domain_url
    self.domain.nil? ? '' : self.domain.domain_url
  end
end
```

### Usage

```
Link.create(href: 'example.com/somepage',
            text: 'Some Page',
            domain_url: 'example.com')
```

### Conclusion

In both cases (your and mine) you get two request (like so):

```
Domain Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."domain" = 'example.com' LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "links" ("href", "text", "domain_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('example.com/somepage', 'Some Page', 5, '2011-04-26 08:51:20.373523', '2011-04-26 08:51:20.373523')
```

But with this code you're also protected from unknown domains, so `Link`'d create one automatically.

Also you can use validates uniqueness so you can remove all `unless Link.exists?(:href => '...')`.

Comment: Learned a few new things from this, thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 2):

```
Domain.where(:domain => 'example.com').
  first.links.
  find_or_create_by_href_and_text(:href => 'example.com/somepage', :text => "Some Page")
```

**UPD**

```
@domain = Domain.where(:domain => 'example.com').
            first.links.
            find_or_create_by_href('example.com/somepage')
@domain.text = "My Text"
@domain.save
```

Or you can use extended `update_or_create_by_*` method:

```
Domain.update_or_create_by_href('example.com/somepage') do |domain|
  domain.text = "My Text"
end
```

More info here:

> [find_or_create_by in Rails 3 and updating for creating records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578625/find-or-create-by-in-rails-3-and-updating-for-creating-records)

Comment: Wouldn't that find_or_create match against both the href AND the text? If I remove the _and_text it would only match against the href, correct?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow.. I need to be able to add the :text, but I only want to match against the :href