# Insert or update with find_or_create_by_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is what I'm doing:-

```
@userdata =find_or_create_by_id(:id=>params[:id])
```

Now how can I know weather I need to use
`@userdata.save` 
or

```
@userdata.update_attributes params[:user_object]
```

And how to pass my user object in case of `@userdata.save`

Comment: you may want [upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by whether to user save or update_attributes. find_or_create_by_id will return a user object, that may or may not be persisted depending on whether validations passed (if it didn't exist already). You can find out by asking `@userdata.persisted?`

In any case, I recommend using first_or_create:

```
@userdata = User.where(:id => params[:id]).first_or_create(params[:user_object])
if @userdata.persisted? 
  # proceed
else
  # errors in params, recover
end
```

UPDATE:
Kiddorails is right about the above code not updating the record if it existed prior to the call. The solution is actually pretty simple. Sorry I didn't get it right the first time:

```
@userdata = User.where(:id => params[:id]).first || User.new
@userdata.update_attributes(params[:user_object])
```

This works because update_attributes works just fine whether the record is new or persisted.

Comment: Its bit confusing can you please explain why you are using persisted?

Comment: And, err.. I don't think `first_or_create` will `update` the attributes if the `User` with that `id` is matched. If it is matched, it will just return the user with that id, without updating with `params[:user_object]`

Comment: So, should I do something like this:  if @userdata.persisted? 
  @userdata.update_attributes params[:user_object]
else
   # Some error occured
end

Comment: No. If the record is new, it would have already `create`d the record earlier, doing `update_attributes` again, won't serve you any purpose. Anyway, see the link I posted in my answer and last comment. That is pretty good solution.

Comment: kiddorails is right, so I have updated my answer with the correct approach.

Comment: @boulder: Bingo! I've also added an `ActiveRecord` helper in your answer which is usually not known; but is perfect to simplify your query :)

Comment: @kiddorails. Thank you for your suggestion. However find_or_initialize_by_id is deprecated in Rails 4; in order to make the answer Rails 4 compatible I've chosen not to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this can help:

```
@userdata = User.find_or_create_by_id(params[:id])
if @userdata.new_record? #=> @userdata is a new record
  #Add attributes
  @userdata.save
else
  @userdata.update_attributes params[:user_object]
end
```

Or even better, make your own method as [Best way to find_or_create_by_id but update the attributes if the record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160073/best-way-to-find-or-create-by-id-but-update-the-attributes-if-the-record-is-foun)

Comment: This is wrong. persisted? => true doesn't mean it's a new record. It returns true whether it's a new record, or it already existed. It will return false only if create failed. Additionally, you can use update_attributes in either case.

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps [new_record?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F) then?

Comment: How to assign the user object in case of @userdata.save?

Comment: Sachin. See my answer below.

Comment: `@userdata.attributes = params[:user_object]`. Though, solution of @boulder is certainly more generic and conventional.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
The first line search object and create if doesn't exist.

```
   userdata = UserModel.where(:id=>params[:id]).first_or_create(:id=>params[:id])
    unless userdata .nil?
      update_attributes params[:user_object]
    end
```